# looking for a class which guarantees accurate packet delivery

Tags: java, sockets

I want to send messages and data packets between 2 Floodlight controllers (which are java based) in a SDN network. To do so, I decided to use socket programming. I started to use a class called `Java.net.DatagramPacket`, but I found out there is **no guarantee** as to whether my messages will be received or not, and they may also arrive out of order.

So my question is: Is there a class in java which provides the guarantee for accurate packet delivery?

Comment: hope [this](http://www.eng.northampton.ac.uk/~espen/CSY2026/TCPJavaProgramming.htm) helps

Comment: Have a look at TCP

Comment: @guleryuz Thanks a lot for this useful link.

Comment: @guleryuz By the way, does *java.net.Socket* class have the same functionality of *Java.net.DatagramPacket* for TCP packets? (It seems more reliable, but I want to know if it can do whatever *Java.net.DatagramPacket* can)

Comment: I don't know whether java Socket classes have any lack of functionality versus Datagram classes. As mentioned [here](https://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips-100019/31-java-net/2044-serversocket-or-datagramsocket-which-one-is-better-to-use-in-my-applications.html) which one you should use depends on task you do